# Google Play Subscriptions API returns: 204 No content

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

I have started implementing Subscriptions into my app but I cannot get the API to work.

I have successfully got an oauth token, but when I request the details about a subscription nothing is returned. I have tried Fiddler, cUrl and the Google API Explorer website. All return 204 No content, regardless of what data is entered.

Is the problem on Google's end or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was on the Google API server. All working now.